TclError preventing creation of Tkinter windows
I have a student on MacOS (Sonoma 14.6.1) getting an error when they try to create a window in a function:
def nothing_window():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.mainloop()

When they call that function in IDLE, they get an error about not having the correct permissions to call the Tk constructor.  Here's the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    nothing_window()
  File "/Users/<username>/Documents/<coursename>/<student_file>.py", line 232, in nothing_window
    window = tkinter.Tk()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2346, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: error getting working directory name: not owner

This problem is also unfortunately preventing them from using the turtle package.
Is there anything they can do so they can use Tkinter in python programs run from IDLE?

How are they launching idle? Have they tried changing their working directory to their home directory? It sounds like idle might think the working directory is root or some other non-writable directory.

@BryanOakley Good question!  They are just clicking on their script in Finder and that opens IDLE.
